# How to get secret your fabric api key or inside gradle.properties file

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Okay..I have got the answer by my own...
here is the code,which helped me :

Follow this steps:-

https://github.com/plastiv/CrashlyticsDemo/

mostly people have to problem run the gradle command line so you can use like this:
1) Open terminal.

2) Go to your project work space

3) ./gradlew

(Note if permission denies error use this command- chmod 744 gradlew and again run ./gradlew)

(4)  ./gradlew assemble -P apiKey=Your fabric api key

Now you can fully secret your api key but remember one thing your fabric.properties looks like that

fabric.properties:-

apiSecret=”Your fabric secret key”
apiKey=”Your fabric api key”

Enjoy!

Comment: This isn't in an appropriate format for the site. Ask a question, then as an answer answer it. It shouldn't all be shoved in the question, and the question needs to ask an actual question.

Answer (score 6):

it just create `fabric.properties` in /app, then just put

```
apiSecret=XXXX
apiKey=XXXX
```

thats all..

Comment: This helped me. The key was that the file should go in the `app` folder, not the project root folder.